# NullPointerException on Edittext

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

i know that this question have been asked before,but no one had an answer for my question.hope i can get the error .

log.d shows that am retrieving `firstname` before i `setText(firstname)` and that what confused me.

my code and the error

```
UserList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // add data here
            fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
            agee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);

            firstname=fname.getText().toString();
            lastname=lname.getText().toString();


            Log.d("filter",firstname);
            Log.d("filter",lastname);

            firstnameupdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstnameupdate);
            lastnameupdate= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lastnameudpate);

            firstnameupdate.setText(firstname);  <==== here is the error 
            lastnameupdate.setText(lastname);

            Intent update = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),update.class);   
            startActivity(update);

        }

    });

    // add onitemlongclick here

}
```

error messages from logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at com.exampl1.quayomobility.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:114)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1287)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3078)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4161)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6455):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

the code is in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

that is what the log.d give me :

```
09-05 01:36:04.737: D/filter(6455): alex
09-05 01:36:04.737: D/filter(6455): bondaro
```

XML containing `firstnameupdate`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstnameupdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

mainActivity file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="10dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addmem_bt_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADD USER" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/memberList_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you indeed point to line # **114** in `MainActivity.java` file, then `firstnameupdate` is `null`.

Comment: Try replacing the line: `firstnameupdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstnameupdate);` with: `firstnameupdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnameupdate);`

Comment: @PM 77-1 that why am confused, i already 'firstnameupdate.setText(firstname)', so it should be set to 'firstname'

Comment: @alfasin i already tried it but i keeps giving me the same error

Comment: @user3476925 show us the xml that contains `firstnameupdate`

Comment: @user3476925 first verify if `view.findViewById(R.id.firstnameupdate)` returns null or not. Then take it from there.

Comment: Post your `MainActivity.xml` file.

Comment: @alfasin how about the error at 'onItemClick' at 118 ? what should that mean.the app is crashing when i click on a user in the listview

Comment: @PM 77-1 'main.xml' added , please check

Comment: Where's your `<EditText>` stuff? In a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

the `View` in onItemClick doesn't seem to locate your `R.id.firstnameupdate` which means the current `View` in your listview doesnt contain the `EditText` with the name `R.id.firstnameupdate`.

if the `EditText` R.id.firstnameupdate is in other xml file. you need to use [Layout inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

```
  LayoutInflater inflator = youractivity.getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflator.inflate(the xml file where firstnameupdate is(R.layout.test, null);
```

then you can locate now the `EditText`

```
firstnameupdate = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstnameupdate);
lastnameupdate= (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lastnameudpate);
```

Comment: what is 'youractivity' in 'LayoutInflater inflator = youractivity.getLayoutInflater();' ? is it the one where 'onClickListener' is ?